# ExpressJS - How to force update session (eli5)?

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies, memcached

I am kind of new to Express and Node (I come from the front-end development world), so this might be a really stupid question.

Currently, I work on an Express JS app that uses `express-session`, `sessionstore` + `memcache` and `cookie-parser` for managing sessions.

I have a particular use case wherein I have one session variable (`age`) that is passed on to every view through a middleware that someone in the team who created the app had written:

`response.locals.age = request.session.age`

The `request.session.age` is populated from a `UserAccount` model that is fetched during login.

Now, this middleware is called before the the request reaches the controller, so by the time I get this in my view, the `response.locals.age` has already been set, which is displayed in the template as is.

My question is this: The `age` variable can be reset separately through an Admin interface. But because the session is set only upon login, the change doesn't reflect until I logout and login again. I do get the new `age` value by fetching the `UserAccount` model again, but I don't know how to refresh the session with the new value without having to logout and login again. I tried doing this:

`req.session.age = res.locals.age = < UserAccountResponse >.age;`

But this doesn't seem to work. What is the ideal way to 'force refresh' the session in this scenario in Express along with the mentioned middlewares? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `req.session.regenerate(function(err) {
  // will have a new session here
})` Did you try regenerate the session? or `req.session.reload(function(err) {
  // session updated
})`

Comment: Both are returning `null` :( No luck